# How can I write the return values of a function into a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I want to write the values returned by `funcStdErrMle` and `funcStdErrMome` into a matrix to show the results for different values of `n` and `theta`. When I try doing this, it shows the following error:

```
**Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = 0.419321467165103) : 
  subscript out of bounds**
```

Here is my code:

```
n <- c(5,10,30,100)
theta <- c(1,2,4)

funcPop_Mean<-function(theta)
{
    pop_mean<-mean(runif(5000,0,theta))
    return(pop_mean)
}

funcMLE<-function(n,theta)
{
    run1 <- runif(n,0,theta)
    mle_est <- max(run1)
    return (mle_est)
}

funcMOME<-function(n,theta)
{
    run2 <- runif(n,0,theta)
    avg<-mean(run2)
    mome_est <- 2*avg
    return (mome_est)
}

funcStdErrMome<-function(n,theta)
{

            diff1 <- funcPop_Mean(theta)-funcMOME(n,theta)
    se_mome <- mean(diff1**2)
    return (se_mome)
}

funcStdErrMle<-function(n,theta)
{

    diff2 <- funcPop_Mean(theta)-funcMLE(n,theta)
    se_mle <- mean(diff2**2)
    return (se_mle)
}

MOME_res <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=4)
MLE_res <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=4)
for(i in theta)
{
    for(j in n)
    {
        MOME_res[i,j] <- funcStdErrMome(i,j)
    }
}
for(i in theta)
{
    for(j in n)
    {
        MLE_res[i,j] <- funcStdErrMle(i,j)
    }
}
```

Comment: The first iteration of the first `for` loop after creating `MOME_res` and `MLE_res` is attempting to assign a value to matrix position `[1, 5]`. By the very definition of them - `matrix(nrow=3, ncol=4)` - that isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes, that is the part where I am not clear. I need my code to iterate through the values in the vector "theta" and "n" instead of the index being iterated. I want the matrix to hold the results corresponding to parameters theta=1 and n=5 in cell [1,1].

Comment: take a look at the code i pasted into the "answer" and let me know if that's the desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying something like that. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does changing the `for` loops to the following arrive at what you need?

```
for(i in 1:length(theta)) {
  for(j in 1:length(n)) {
    MOME_res[i, j] <- funcStdErrMome(theta[i], n[j])
  }
}

for(i in 1:length(theta)) {
  for(j in 1:length(n)) {
    MLE_res[i, j] <- funcStdErrMle(theta[i], n[j])
  }
}
```